# Modal boostrap no se muestra en una página

Tags: html, css, modal, bootstrap

> EDIT 1: Encontré que el boton no funciona estando dentro de las etiquetas `<form>`, fuera de ellas sí lo hace. Pero yo necesito el botón dentro, así que sigo con el problema

-

> Buenos días, me está pasando algo extraño. Tengo dos páginas en mi sitio web, y en las dos se pueden agregar nuevos clientes. El tema es que en `clientes.php` el modal `#modalAgregarCliente` se abre y funciona perfecto.
>   Ahora, en la otra pagina llamada `crear-menu.php` tengo un elemento html `select` para elegir al cliente, y al lado del elemento, un `button` para agregar un nuevo cliente si no existiera. Tanto el `button` como el `modal` son un `copypaste` de `clientes.php` hacia `crear-menu.php`.
>
> Y cuando doy click al boton **Agregar Cliente** de mi `crear-menu.php`, el modal no se abre.

**clientes.php**

```html
<!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
    <section class="content-header">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row mb-2">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <h1>Clientes<small> - Viejo Almacén</small></h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <ol class="breadcrumb float-sm-right">

                        <li class="breadcrumb-item"> <i class="fas fa-users"></i></li>
                        <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Clientes</li>
                    </ol>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </section>

    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">

        <!-- Default box -->
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <button class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalAgregarCliente">
                    Agregar Cliente
                </button>
            </div>



            <div class="card-body">
                <table class="table table-bordered table-striped dt-responsive tablaClientes" width="100%">

                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="width:10px">#</th>
                            <th>Partido</th>
                            <th>Municipio</th>
                            <th>Org. Gubernamental</th>
                            <th>Establecimiento</th>
                            <th>CUIT</th>
                            <th>Cupos</th>
                            <th>Tipo</th>
                            <th>Acciones</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>


                    <tbody>

                        <?php

                            $item = null;
                            $valor = null;

                            $clientes = ControladorClientes::ctrMostrarClientes($item, $valor);


                            foreach ($clientes as $key => $value){

                                $tipo;
                                if($value["tipo"] == "mun"){
                                    $tipo = '<i class="fab fa-medium-m" title="Municipalizado"></i>';
                                }else{
                                    $tipo = '<i class="fab fa-product-hunt" title="Provincial"></i>';
                                }

                                echo '
                                <tr>
                                <td>'.($key + 1).'</td>
                                <td>'.$value["partido"].'</td>
                                <td>'.$value["municipio"].'</td>
                                <td>'.$value["organo"].'</td>
                                <td>'.$value["establecimiento"].'</td>
                                <td>'.$value["cuit"].'</td>
                                <td>'.$value["cupos"].'</td>
                                <td>'.$tipo.'</td>
                                <td>
                                    <button class="btn btn-warning btnEditarCliente" idCliente="'.$value["id"].'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEditarCliente"><i class="fa fa-pencil-alt"></i></button>
                                    <button class="btn btn-danger btnEliminarCliente" idCliente="'.$value["id"].'"s><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                                ';
                            }

                            ?>



                    </tbody>





                </table>
            </div>
            <!-- /.card-body -->

        </div>
        <!-- /.card -->

    </section>
    <!-- /.content -->
</div>


<!-- =========================================
MODAL AGREGAR CLIENTE
=========================================  -->


<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modalAgregarCliente" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalAgregarCliente"
    aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">


            <form role="form" method="post" action="">


                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Agregar Cliente</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="form-group">

                            <!-- Entrada para el partido Cliente -->
                            <div class="form-group">

                                <div class="input-group">

                                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                        <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1"><i
                                                class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i></span>
                                    </div>

                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="nuevoPartido" name="nuevoPartido"
                                        placeholder="Ingrese Partido" required>

                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <!-- Entrada para el municipio de Cliente -->
                            <div class="form-group">

                                <div class="input-group">

                                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                        <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1"><i
                                                class="fas fa-thumbtack"></i></span>
                                    </div>

                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="nuevoMunicipio" name="nuevoMunicipio"
                                        placeholder="Ingrese Municipio" required>

                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <!-- Entrada para el organo gubernamental -->

                            <div class="form-group">

                                <div class="input-group">

                                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                        <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1"><i
                                                class="fas fa-university"></i></span>
                                    </div>

                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="nuevoOrgano" name="nuevoOrgano"
                                        placeholder="Ingrese Órgano Gubernamental">

                                </div>

                            </div>


                            <!-- Entrada para el establecimiento -->

                            <div class="form-group">

                                <div class="input-group">

                                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                        <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1"><i
                                                class="fas fa-graduation-cap"></i></span>
                                    </div>

                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="nuevoEstablecimiento"
                                        name="nuevoEstablecimiento" placeholder="Ingrese nombre del establecimiento"
                                        required>

                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <!-- Entrada para el CUIT -->

                            <div class="form-group">

                                <div class="input-group">

                                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                        <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1"><i
                                                class="fas fa-money-check"></i></span>
                                    </div>

                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="nuevoCuit" name="nuevoCuit"
                                        placeholder="Ingrese CUIT">

                                </div>
                                <span class="small">Sin Guiones, sólo números</span>

                            </div>


                            <!-- Entrada para el numero de cupos -->

                            <div class="form-group">

                                <div class="input-group">

                                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                        <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1"><i
                                                class="fas fa-universal-access"></i></span>
                                    </div>

                                    <input class="form-control" type="number" id="nuevoCupo" name="nuevoCupo"
                                        placeholder="Ingrese numero de cupos" required>

                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <div class="input-group">

                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1"><i
                                            class="far fa-check-circle"></i></span>
                                </div>

                                <select class="form-control" name="nuevoTipo" required>
                                    <option value="">Seleccione tipo de cliente</option>
                                    <option value="mun">Municipalizado</option>
                                    <option value="prov">Provincial</option>





                                </select>


                            </div>






                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Guardar</button>
                </div>


                <?php

                     $crearCliente = new ControladorClientes();
                     $crearCliente -> ctrCrearCliente();
                 ?>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**crear-menu.php**

```html
<!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
    <section class="content-header">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row mb-2">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <h1>Menús<small> - Viejo Almacén</small></h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <ol class="breadcrumb float-sm-right">

                        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><i class="fas fa-users-cog"></i></li>
                        <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Menús</li>
                    </ol>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </section>

    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">

        <div class="row">

            <!-- FORMULARIO DE NUEVO MENÚ-->
            <div class="col-lg-7 col-xs-12">

                <div class="card border border-success">

                    <div class="card-body">

                        <form role="form" method="post">


                            <!-- ENTRADA PARA EL NOMBRE DEL MENÚ-->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="input-group">

                                    <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nuevoMenu" name="nuevoMenu"
                                        placeholder="Ingrese nombre del menú">


                                </div>
                            </div>



                            <!-- ENTRADA PARA SELECCIONAR EL CLIENTE-->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="input-group">

                                    <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                                    <select class="form-control" name="" id="">
                                        <option value="">Seleccione Cliente</option>

                                    </select>
                                    <span class="input-group-prepend">
                                        <button class="btn btn-success btn-xs" data-toggle="modal"
                                            data-target="#modalAgregarCliente">
                                            Agregar Cliente
                                        </button>
                                    </span>

                                </div>
                            </div>




                        </form>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>


    </section>
    <!-- /.content -->
</div>



<!-- =========================================
MODAL AGREGAR CLIENTE
=========================================  -->


<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modalAgregarCliente" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalAgregarCliente"
    aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">


            <form role="form" method="post" action="">


                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Agregar Cliente</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="form-group">

                            <!-- Entrada para el partido Cliente -->
                            <div class="form-group">

                                <div class="input-group">

                                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                        <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1"><i
                                                class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i></span>
                                    </div>

                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="nuevoPartido" name="nuevoPartido"
                                        placeholder="Ingrese Partido" required>

                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <!-- Entrada para el municipio de Cliente -->
                            <div class="form-group">

                                <div class="input-group">

                                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                        <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1"><i
                                                class="fas fa-thumbtack"></i></span>
                                    </div>

                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="nuevoMunicipio" name="nuevoMunicipio"
                                        placeholder="Ingrese Municipio" required>

                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <!-- Entrada para el organo gubernamental -->

                            <div class="form-group">

                                <div class="input-group">

                                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                        <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1"><i
                                                class="fas fa-university"></i></span>
                                    </div>

                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="nuevoOrgano" name="nuevoOrgano"
                                        placeholder="Ingrese Órgano Gubernamental">

                                </div>

                            </div>


                            <!-- Entrada para el establecimiento -->

                            <div class="form-group">

                                <div class="input-group">

                                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                        <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1"><i
                                                class="fas fa-graduation-cap"></i></span>
                                    </div>

                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="nuevoEstablecimiento"
                                        name="nuevoEstablecimiento" placeholder="Ingrese nombre del establecimiento"
                                        required>

                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <!-- Entrada para el CUIT -->

                            <div class="form-group">

                                <div class="input-group">

                                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                        <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1"><i
                                                class="fas fa-money-check"></i></span>
                                    </div>

                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="nuevoCuit" name="nuevoCuit"
                                        placeholder="Ingrese CUIT">

                                </div>
                                <span class="small">Sin Guiones, sólo números</span>

                            </div>


                            <!-- Entrada para el numero de cupos -->

                            <div class="form-group">

                                <div class="input-group">

                                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                        <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1"><i
                                                class="fas fa-universal-access"></i></span>
                                    </div>

                                    <input class="form-control" type="number" id="nuevoCupo" name="nuevoCupo"
                                        placeholder="Ingrese numero de cupos" required>

                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <div class="input-group">

                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1"><i
                                            class="far fa-check-circle"></i></span>
                                </div>

                                <select class="form-control" name="nuevoTipo" required>
                                    <option value="">Seleccione tipo de cliente</option>
                                    <option value="mun">Municipalizado</option>
                                    <option value="prov">Provincial</option>





                                </select>


                            </div>






                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Guardar</button>
                </div>


                <?php

                    $crearCliente = new ControladorClientes();
                    $crearCliente -> ctrCrearCliente();
                ?>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya lo solucioné. Como dice en el EDIT1, no podía tener el botón de llamada al modal dentro del `form` y el modal por fuera. Así que metí el `modal` antes del cierre de la etiqueta `form` y funcionó a la perfección.